How to stop a material from casting shadows
I have an object with multiple materials and I want only one of the materials to not cast any shadow at all. I am aware how to turn off shadows on a mesh but I can't seam to find a way to turn off shadow on only one material without affecting the way it looks. Some way with light paths perhaps?

For Eevee: go in Properties Editor > Material Tab > Settings Panel > Shadow Mode, set it to None:

